# Constructing a tree structure from table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a similar requirement as this question at:
[What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

In my case, the table can contain potentially a millions of row, the depth of the node structure to the root may be around 5 to 6, but the breadth of the nodes could be huge,

I am using entity framework C#, is there a fast and efficient algorithm by which we can figure out the structure via entity?

Comment: I'm not sure your question contains enough information to form an answer, and if it did I'm not sure it would be on topic / within scope for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you have DataTable, you can try something like this (recursive function):

```
private void FillTree(TreeNode pnode,DataTable data)
    {
        DataRow[] cnodes = data.Select("catparent=" + pnode.Tag.ToString());
        foreach (DataRow crow in cnodes)
        {
            TreeNode ctn = new TreeNode(crow["catname"].ToString());
            ctn.Name = "Cat" + crow["cat_id"].ToString();
            ctn.Tag = crow["cat_id"].ToString();
            pnode.Nodes.Add(ctn);
            FillTree(ctn, data);
        }
    }
```

This is  my table structure:

[image: This is my table structure:]

Comment: In my case I am passing RootTreeNode with Tag=0, so at first execution it will get all parent node or main category and add them under root node.